# sum by id mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to sum all total_harga by id_subkategori, how i caan get that? so just get for example all id_subkategori 5 get sum
[my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c94Q4.png)

Comment: You can find the SUM of the column Using GROUP BY , take a look at this :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY id_subkategori` to get the desired output.

```
select sum(total_harga) total, id_subkategori
from yourtable
group by id_subkategori
```

You can read more on aggregate functions [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-aggregate-functions.aspx)

**Edit:**

If you want to pick for a specific id_subkategori, you need to change it like following.

```
select sum(total_harga) total, id_subkategori
from yourtable
where id_subkategori=5
group by id_subkategori
```

Comment: i get it, but how i just show the sum result for id_subkategori 5 not show all?

Comment: <td colspan="7">Total Pemasukan</td>
    <?php 
    $total_pemasukan = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select sum(total_harga) as total, id_subkategori from barang_laku group by id_subkategori");  
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($total_pemasukan)){
      //echo $row['total'];
      echo "<td><b> Rp.". number_format($row['total']).",-</b></td>";

    }
    
?>

Comment: You need to put a where condition like "where id_subkategori = 5" to pick a  specific id_subkategori

Answer (score 0):

Use a sql statement to sum the total.

```
select sum(total_harga) total
from yourtable
where id_subkategori = 5
group by id_subkategori
```

Then fetch the sql result by PHP. Please check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) for your reference.